# sql server trigger to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-trigger

I'm trying to migrate an SQL Server 2012 trigger to MySQL. The trigger helps to create a hierarchical path for a tree of parent-child nodes which looks something like ".level1.level2.level3" and so on. However, I'm having some issues getting it to work. Here is the SQL Sever trigger creation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_TiersPath] ON [dbo].[Tiers] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
        -- This trigger will update the hierarchy diagram for the inserted/updated node and all descendants.

    IF (UPDATE(ParentID))  -- Ignore updates to other data fields
    BEGIN
            -- First, all updated nodes will start with the same string: the new hierarchy diagram of the
            --  updated/inserted node.  Find this first, then use it as the base for all updated values.
        DECLARE @newDiagramStart VARCHAR(MAX)  

            -- Just use a dot if this is the top of the hierarchy. Otherwise, obtain the hierarchy diagram of the new parent.
        SELECT @newDiagramStart = ISNULL(Tiers.TierPath, '.') FROM inserted LEFT JOIN Tiers ON Tiers.TierID = inserted.ParentID  

            -- Append the inserted/updated node ID.
        SELECT @newDiagramStart = @newDiagramStart + CAST(TierID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '.' FROM inserted 

            -- Now update the hierarchy diagram for the inserted/updated node and any descendants.
        UPDATE NodesDescendants
            -- Find the existing hierarchy diagram after the node ID of the inserted/updated node, and append it.
        SET TierPath = @newDiagramStart + ISNULL(RIGHT(NodesDescendants.TierPath, LEN(NodesDescendants.TierPath) - LEN(inserted.TierPath)),'')  
        FROM inserted 
            INNER JOIN Tiers AS NodesDescendants 
            ON NodesDescendants.TierID = inserted.TierID        -- Update the inserted/updated node.
            OR NodesDescendants.TierPath LIKE inserted.TierPath + '%'  -- Update all descendants.
    END

END
;
```

So far, this is what I have for the Insert portion of the equivalent MySQL trigger:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_TiersPath
BEFORE INSERT
ON Tiers FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE newDiagramStart LONGTEXT;
   CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS InsTiers
   (
      TierID VARCHAR(50),
      ParentID VARCHAR(50),
      OrgID VARCHAR(50),
      TierPath VARCHAR(2048),
      Active CHAR(1),
      CreatedON DATETIME,
      CreatedBY VARCHAR(50),
      BatchID INT
   );
   DELETE FROM InsTiers;
   INSERT INTO InsTiers  VALUES(NEW.TierID, NEW.ParentID, NEW.OrgID, NEW.TierPath, NEW.Active, NEW.CreatedON, NEW.CreatedBY, NEW.BatchID);
   BEGIN
        -- This trigger will update the hierarchy diagram for the inserted/updated node and all descendants.

      IF (1 = 1) then  -- Ignore updates to other data fields

            -- First, all updated nodes will start with the same string: the new hierarchy diagram of the
            --  updated/inserted node.  Find this first, then use it as the base for all updated values.


            -- Just use a dot if this is the top of the hierarchy. Otherwise, obtain the hierarchy diagram of the new parent.
         select   IFNULL(Tiers.TierPath,'.') INTO newDiagramStart FROM InsTiers inserted LEFT JOIN Tiers ON Tiers.TierID = inserted.ParentID;  

            -- Append the inserted/updated node ID.     
            -- Find the existing hierarchy diagram after the node ID of the inserted/updated node, and append it.
            -- Update the inserted/updated node.
         SET newDiagramStart = CONCAT_WS('', newDiagramStart, CAST(NEW.TierID AS CHAR), '.'); 

            -- Now update the hierarchy diagram for the inserted/updated node and any descendants.
         NEW.TierPath = CONCAT_WS('',newDiagramStart,IFNULL(RIGHT(NULL, CHAR_LENGTH(NULL) - CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.TierPath)),''));

      end if;
   END;
END;
//
```

However, this fails due to some syntax error related to both of the CONCAT_WS lines. I just can't see it. I'm open to suggestions to fix this; or even, finding a better approach to achieve the same ends. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with keeping the whole ".level1.level2.level3" type of concatenated path. In my case those "levels" are actually IDs.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: The sql-server trigger code is `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` the MySQL trigger code is `BEFORE INSERT` thats not equivalent beside you need to write two triggers in MySQL. one AFTER INSERT and a AFTER UPDATE

Comment: Any particular reason for not sharing the exact error message?

Comment: I understand that there are two triggers needed that is why I mentioned the "Insert portion" before showing the mysql trigger. As far as the actual error, sure: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.TierPath = CONCAT_WS('',newDiagramStart,IFNULL(RIGHT(NULL, CHAR_LENGTH(NULL) - ' at line 37

Comment: Raymond: I understand the need for two triggers which is why I mentioned the "Insert portion" atop the mysql trigger code.

Comment: Shadow: the error message: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 48: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.TierPath = CONCAT_WS('',newDiagramStart,IFNULL(RIGHT(OLD.TierPath, CHAR_LENGTH(' at line 35